# Random Number Generation in R

Tags: r, random

I am looking to generate a set of five random numbers in R. The tricky part however is that I wish for the values to be in a sequence that is first decreasing, then increasing: that is, the first random number will be larger than the second, which will be larger than the third. The fourth will be larger than the third, and the fifth will be larger than the fourth. To explain this more clearly, 1=High, 2=Mid, 3=Low, 4=Mid, 5=High; while still maintaining a mean of (approximately) 2000 for the largest (first and last) values.

I suppose the first and fifth values should be around 2000, the second and fourth values can be around 1500 but I imagine can fluctuate quite a bit, and the third value should be relatively lower. The SD can vary as well.

So for example, a satisfactory string could be:

```
2300, 1843, 987, 1300, 1900
```

To bring in some biological background, I am attempting to describe a complex system in the patterns of abundance in oystercatchers based on the tides. I know from data that the mean value for oystercatchers while the tide is low is ~2000. The values for mid and high tide however are not known for this particular estuary. I imagine that high tide will have lower numbers than mid and low tide.

Comment: What would be the mean of the Mid and Low sets?

Comment: hints: `?order`.  Do you want the mean to be *exactly* 2000, in which case you'll have to use something like `x <- 2000*x/mean(x)` ?

Comment: To bring in some biological background, I am attempting to describe a complex system in the patterns of abundance in oystercatchers based on the tides. I know from data that the mean value for oystercatchers while the tide is low is ~2000. The values for mid and high tide however are not known for this particular estuary. I imagine that high tide will have lower numbers than mid and low tide. Therefore if it is possible to keep 2000 as the mean, but have the numbers randomly generated with some kind of weight to them, that would be the ideal scenario.

Comment: Could you post an example of 5 numbers that would satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Yes, sorry! 5 numbers could be the following: 2,300, 1,843, 987, 1,300, 1,900

Comment: Um, `x = runif(5); z = sort(x)[c(5,3,1,2,4)] - mean(x) + 2000`

Comment: I have added your example values to to question (by editing it). I guess what you need is kinda sinus wave with random fluctuations

Comment: @RYoda could you please give an example of a sinus wave with random fluctuations as you describe? Sorry, I am new to using R for things other than GLMs!

Comment: I think this should be reopened now.  A solution: `x <- -2:2; y <- 1000 + 500*x^2; r <- rpois(5,lambda=y)` (or `r <- rnbinom(5,mu=y,size=1)` if you need the results to be more variable)

Comment: @RyanRothman Sorry, I have no R code for that (out of my experiences). I just tried to rephrase your requirements

Comment: your question is now inconsistent.  The top part says the mean should be 2000; the bottom part says the maximum (edge) values should be around 2000, with the central values lower.  Can you please edit/clarify?  Also, it would be good to include the biological context that you gave in your comment as part of your question.

Comment: @BenBolker Apologies, I incorrectly stated at the top that I wished for my mean to be 2000. As you state, the maximum values for the 1st and 5th values should be around 2,000 with the inner values being lower. The code supplied by RYoda seems to deliver the desired output:                                                                  rnd.values <- rnorm(5, mean=2000, sd=1000)
ordered.rnd.values <- rnd.values[order(rnd.values, decreasing=TRUE)]
result <- c(ordered.rnd.values[1:2], ordered.rnd.values[5], ordered.rnd.values[4:3])
result

Comment: it's probably better *not* to answer the question in your answer.  You could either post it as your own answer to your question (which is allowed), or preferably wait a bit first to see if @RYoda chooses to undelete their answer ...

Comment: I wouldn't reopen. I guess that it will be an edit after edit after edit. OP, you should clarify your mind. It appears to me that the requirements are still unclear to you. Let this question go, think about this topic a little further and come back (if you still are not satisfied with the proposed solutions) when you have a clearer picture. Another reason *not* to reopen is that it seems unlikely that this question could help others.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me now (and potentially useful) -- but of course that's just my opinion.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing. Feel free to roll back/edit if you don't like what I did. Your statement in the second para. about the values of the second and fourth elements was inconsistent (you said they should be around 2000 as well), so I took a guess based on your example.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes thank you. I have run the code from RYoda a few times now, and I believe that it is satisfactory for the purposes of my experiment. Is there a way to return the answer?

Comment: @RYoda Could you please undelete your answer to this question? After running it a few times I believe the code be sufficient for my model (after altering the sd value to 1000). Thank you very much.

Comment: @RyanRothman: a reasonable convention is to wait a little while (a few hours?  a day?) to give them a chance to undelete it if they want to.  If not, go ahead and post the answer yourself (giving them credit in the text of your answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said be Ben Bolker:

```
rnd.values <- rnorm(5, mean=2000, sd=1)
rnd.values
# [1] 1999.909 1999.656 2001.798 2000.352 2000.114

ordered.rnd.values <- rnd.values[order(rnd.values, decreasing=TRUE)]
ordered.rnd.values
# [1] 2001.798 2000.352 2000.114 1999.909 1999.656

# stupid solution to make the 3rd element the minimum
result <- c(ordered.rnd.values[1:2], ordered.rnd.values[5], ordered.rnd.values[4:3])
result
# [1] 2001.798 2000.352 1999.656 1999.909 2000.114
```

Comment: decreasing=TRUE would be the ideal way to go, if the values could decrease up until the 3rd integer, then go back upward for the 4th and 5th?

Comment: A yes, I overlooked that. This requires a second `order` but which higher values shall I choose (any interdependencies between the values 1 and 2 with 4 and 5?

Comment: I suppose the 1st and 5th values should be around 2000, the 2nd and 4th values can be around 2000 but I imagine can fluctuate quite a bit, and the 3rd value should be relatively lower. The SD can be very varied as well. So for example, a satisfactory string could be: 2,300, 1,843, 987, 1,300, 1,900.

Comment: @RyanRothman I have undeleted my answer even though I think it is not exactly what you wanted (the right side of the minimum in index 3 always contains lower values than the left side so it is not really random).

Comment: for the purposes of my model it should suffice. Thank you very much for your help on this! =-)